# Registering multiple click events programatically (Android/Java)

Tags: java, android

So i have this program which create my list of cards which are relative layouts and they look like this.

[image: relative layouts]

Here is the code of it creation. Ps its in a for loop

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) atv.getSystemService(atv.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                LinearLayout relativeLayoutz = (LinearLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.rtl_enterprise, parent);

                RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) relativeLayoutz.findViewById(R.id.rl_empresa);
                rl.setId(i);
                ImageView img = (ImageView) rl.getChildAt(0);

                //
                //Performance bottleneck needs fixing/ not loading all images and overloading thread
                //
                //loadImageByUrl(atv, enterprises.getEnterprises().get(k).getPhoto().toString(), img);

                TextView txt = (TextView) rl.getChildAt(1);
                txt.setText(enterprises.getEnterprises().get(i).getEnterpriseName());

                TextView txt2 = (TextView) rl.getChildAt(2);
                txt2.setText(enterprises.getEnterprises().get(i).getEnterpriseType().getEnterpriseTypeName());

                TextView txt3 = (TextView) rl.getChildAt(3);
                txt3.setText(enterprises.getEnterprises().get(i).getCountry());

                LinearLayout relativeLayout = (LinearLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.rtl_enterprise, parent);
                relativeLayout.setId(i);
```

everything there works kinda ok, but i have a problem, i need to create a

> onClick listener

Why? 
I would call a method which needs some info about the card that has been clicked, and then redirect to a new activity which contains the info about the card that he clicked.

But i would need that onclick listener for each of these relative layouts, and i assume it would need to be initialized when the card is created since it create + 50 cards, but i have no idea of how to setup each listener.

Comment: use addOnClickListener inside the for loop aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you create it like that?

a better solution to use RecyclerView.

and in the adapter, you can listen for the item click. write the code one time and when any item clicked. you will know the position of the clicked item.

see this tutorial

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: As Momen says, there are better containers ready made for this kind of stuff, starting with ListView/RecyclerView. But if you *must* do it this way, note that onClick is onClick(View v) and you can use the same function for all the items because you'll receive the clicked item when it's called. Just call setOnClickListener(same_on_click_handler) when you create the components. Just to be clear, I don't recommend it either.

Comment: i just starting developing in java/android so what i did was what i thought it would be right, since thats too specific i didn't found the "correct" way to do it, thanks :D